# How do I install Windows 8 (from an ISO) using Q (qemu)?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-8-preview, qemu

I have downloaded an ISO image of Windows 8 from Microsoft Dreamspark and I am on a 27" iMac without administrative privileges. I would like to install and run Windows. The only way I found to do so is to use Q (Mac port of qemu with a GUI). But I can't figure out how to get it set up. Any pointers?

Comment: Are you sure Q will even install without administrative privileges? Also, it appears to be discontinued, so it's probably unsupported anyway.

Comment: I have Q installed. And the latter may be true but I'd like to at least be able to find out.